# Why do i receive duplicate entry error whenever I generate a singned APK?

Tags: android, build.gradle, apk

I am trying to generate a singned APK for my app and but I don't know  what's wrong in my build files, I receive this error message in the message view:
Cause:: duplicate entry :NOTICE
I have searched a lot to understand why this is happening but in vain

Any help will be very appreciated :)

Here is my build (Module:app) :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.naturesounds"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.4.0'

implementation 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.1'
}
```

And here is my build (project) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Update:
I have look in my project libraries and found many NOTICE files , are they might causing this problem?

Comment: Could you please post the full error message?

Comment: It's just saying :                              
 Cause: duplicate entry :NOTICE          
 in the build output

Answer (score 0):

That is because your project has multiple release apks in the release folder.

Go to your projects - app - build - outputs - apk -

Here u will see debug and release folder.

Go to release folder and delete all the data from it. Now clean..rebuild project in studio and generate signed apk.

Comment: I did this and nothing changed

Comment: Delete all contents from debug folder as well

Comment: Was there apk present in release folder When u deleted?

Comment: Yes there were 1 but in the debug

Comment: Ok so me u hv cleared release nd debug recheck once and then go to file in studio and invalidate nd restart studio

Comment: If his doesn't works then delete all contents from build...outputs folder and restart studio

Comment: I did all of that and the problem still there :)

Comment: Bro the logcat isn't running because i am not running the app on a device??

Comment: U get it in build.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the last line in the build.gradle
(Module:app)  which is :
implementation 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.6.1'

and the problem solved despite I got an error requesting this dependency the first time I tried to sign my APK, maybe some solution from what @Prajwal Waingankar mentioned helped in this